# Incompatible return type in Java

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, incompatibility

I have the following method: (from this WSDL URL:
http://services.aonaware.com/DictService/DictService.asmx?WSDL
)

```
private static WordDefinition define(java.lang.String word) {
    com.aonaware.services.webservices.DictService service = new com.aonaware.services.webservices.DictService();
    com.aonaware.services.webservices.DictServiceSoap port = service.getDictServiceSoap();

    return port.define(word);
}
```

It takes a word from a jTextField and returns a list of its definitions.

I have declared the following list:

```
List<WordDefinition> def = new ArrayList<WordDefinition>();
```

I want to print the result I get from the method. So I made the following loop:

```
    for (int i=0; i< def.size(); i++){
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(def));
    }
```

where:

```
    String str = jTextField1.getText();
    def = define(str);
```

The error is get is the following:

> Incompatible types: List cannot be converted to Object[]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which line are you getting the error

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the list to an array for Arrays.deepToString() to accept it: `Arrays.deepToString(def.toArray())`

Answer (score 0):

I see a lot of confusion.

First of all, the static method `define` returns you a `WordDefinition`, not a `List<WordDefinition>`, so the line

```
def = define(str)
```

should give you a compile error.

Anyway, assuming `List<WordDefinition> def` is actually the variable you have with content, either you use `Arrays.deepToString` OR you iterate over the List, not both.

If you want to iterate, you can just do:

```
for(WordDefinition wd: def){
    System.out.println(wd);
}
```

or

```
Arrays.deepToString(def.toArray());
```